# Predict a value using the "output equation" of a heckit-model (sampleSelection)

Tags: r, predict

I estimate a heckit-model using the heckit-model from sampleSelection.

The model looks as follows:
`library(sampleSelection) Heckman = heckit(AgencyTRACE ~ SizeCat + log(Amt_Issued)  + log(daysfromissuance) + log(daystomaturity) + EoW + dMon + EoM + VIX_95_Dummy + quarter, Avg_Spread_Choi ~ SizeCat + log(Amt_Issued)  + log(daysfromissuance) + log(daystomaturity) + VIX_95_Dummy + TresholdHYIG_II, data=heckmandata, method = "2step")`

The summary generates a probit selection equation and an outcome equation - see below:

```
Tobit 2 model (sample selection model)
2-step Heckman / heckit estimation
2019085 observations (1915401 censored and 103684 observed)
26 free parameters (df = 2019060)
Probit selection equation:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            0.038164   0.043275   0.882    0.378    
SizeCat2               0.201571   0.003378  59.672  < 2e-16 ***
SizeCat3               0.318331   0.008436  37.733  < 2e-16 ***
log(Amt_Issued)       -0.099472   0.001825 -54.496  < 2e-16 ***
log(daysfromissuance)  0.079691   0.001606  49.613  < 2e-16 ***
log(daystomaturity)   -0.036434   0.001514 -24.066  < 2e-16 ***
EoW                    0.021169   0.003945   5.366 8.04e-08 ***
dMon                  -0.003409   0.003852  -0.885    0.376    
EoM                    0.008937   0.007000   1.277    0.202    
VIX_95_Dummy1          0.088558   0.006521  13.580  < 2e-16 ***
quarter2019.2         -0.092681   0.005202 -17.817  < 2e-16 ***
quarter2019.3         -0.117021   0.005182 -22.581  < 2e-16 ***
quarter2019.4         -0.059833   0.005253 -11.389  < 2e-16 ***
quarter2020.1         -0.005230   0.004943  -1.058    0.290    
quarter2020.2          0.073175   0.005080  14.406  < 2e-16 ***
Outcome equation:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            46.29436    6.26019   7.395 1.41e-13 ***
SizeCat2              -25.63433    0.79836 -32.109  < 2e-16 ***
SizeCat3              -34.25275    1.48030 -23.139  < 2e-16 ***
log(Amt_Issued)        -0.38051    0.39506  -0.963  0.33547    
log(daysfromissuance)   0.02452    0.34197   0.072  0.94283    
log(daystomaturity)     7.92338    0.24498  32.343  < 2e-16 ***
VIX_95_Dummy1          -2.34875    0.89133  -2.635  0.00841 ** 
TresholdHYIG_II1       10.36993    1.07267   9.667  < 2e-16 ***
Multiple R-Squared:0.0406,  Adjusted R-Squared:0.0405
   Error terms:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
invMillsRatio -23.8204     3.6910  -6.454 1.09e-10 ***
sigma          68.5011         NA      NA       NA    
rho            -0.3477         NA      NA       NA
```

Now I'd like to estimate a value using the outcome equation. I'd like to predict `Spread_Choi_All` using the following data:

```
newdata = data.frame(SizeCat=as.factor(1),
                                  Amt_Issued=50*1000000,
                                  daysfromissuance=5*365,
                                  daystomaturity=5*365,
                                  VIX_95_Dummy=as.factor(0),
                                  TresholdHYIG_II=as.factor(0)
```

SizeCat is a categorical/factor variable with the value 1, 2 or 3.

I have tried varies ways, i.e.

```
predict(Heckman, part ="outcome", newdata = newdata)
```

I aim to predict a value (with the data from `newdata`) using the outcome equation (incl. the invMillsRatio). Is there a way how to predict a value from the outcome equation?

Comment: Are you getting an error when using `predict`? If so what is the error? Also it seems your equation has A lot more variables when you listed in `newdata`. The data should include all your variables that you have in the formula.

Comment: Hi Oliver, Thank you. Since I'd like to predict only the "outcome equation", the data in 'newdata' should contain all relevant variables. The error is: Fehler in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  Kontraste können nur auf Faktoren mit 2 oder mehr Stufen angewendet werden

Comment: With my limited knowledge of Dutch (or german?), it sounds like the error is coming from one of your factors. Instead of using `as.factor`, you likely should use `factor(1, levels = ...)`. Eg. `SizeCat = factor(1, levels = levels(heckmandata$SizeCat))` to ensure that the factor has the same number of levels. This is likely a limitation of how the authors of the package has implemented the model matrix.

Comment: (use `Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")` to get error in English)

Comment: the error message in english: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: Hello, Oliver. I tried to implement your suggestion, but the same error occurred. I also studied the structure of the package but did not find out how to estimate the "outcome equation" with values...